# Find Derivative If of $x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$ If Exists

Tags: calculus, limits

If there is a derivative find it and evaluate it:

$$
f(X)=
\begin{cases}
x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^2}), x\neq 0\\
0, x=0\\
\end{cases}
$$

My Answer:

Let assume that the limit exists (one can take the derivative of $x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^2})=2x\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})-\frac{2}{x}\cos(\frac{1}{x^2})$

Using the definition of a limit:

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^2\sin\big(\frac{1}{(x+h)^2}\big)-x^2\sin\big(\frac{1}{x^2}\big)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x^2+2xh+h^2)\sin\big(\frac{1}{(x+h)^2}\big)-x^2\sin\big(\frac{1}{x^2}\big)}{h}$$

Because we assume the limit exists we can break it up

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x^2\sin\big(\frac{1}{(x+h)^2}\big)-x^2\sin\big(\frac{1}{x^2}\big)}{h}+\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2xh\sin\big(\frac{1}{(x+h)^2}\big)}{h}+\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^2\sin\big(\frac{1}{(x+h)^2}\big)}{h}$$

$$x^2\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\big(\sin\big(\frac{1}{(x+h)^2}\big)-\sin\big(\frac{1}{x^2}\big)\big)}{h}+2x\lim_{h\to 0}{\sin\big(\frac{1}{(x+h)^2}\big)}+\lim_{h\to 0}{h\sin\big(\frac{1}{(x+h)^2}\big)}$$

The first limit is by definition, the second limit at a constant is a constant and the third is a bounded function times a function that goes to $0$

$$x^2\cos\big(\frac{1}{x^2}\big)\cdot-2x^{-3}+2x{\sin\big(\frac{1}{x^2}\big)}+0=2x{\sin\big(\frac{1}{x^2}\big)}-\frac{2}{x}\cos\big(\frac{1}{x^2}\big)$$

Is it correct?

Can $x^2 \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\big(\sin\big(\frac{1}{(x+h)^2}\big)-\sin\big(\frac{1}{x^2}\big)\big)}{h}$ be evaluate using trig identites

Comment: For $x \neq 0$ the function is differentiable because products, compositions and reciprocals (with denominator $\neq 0$) of differentiable functions are differentiable. You can  use chain rule and product rule to write down the derivative.  At $x=0$ differentiabilty is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given function is continuous as $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} h^2 \sin (1/h^2)=0$ by sandwich theorem:$ -h^2 \le  h^2 \sin(1/h^2) \le h^2.$

$RD=f'(0)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{h^2 \sin\frac{1}{h^2}-0}{h}=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}  h \sin(1/h^2)=0.$
This limit vanishes by sandwich theorem as $-h \le h \sin(1/h^2) \le h,$ Similarly $LD=f'(0)=0.$ so the derivative exists at $x=0$ and it vanishes there.